# add product programmatically magento 2: Undefined property: stdClass::$reference

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, create-product

I went to the backend of magento I added a reference attribute for product,
then I executed the script Programmatically to add product I put:

```
$_product->setName($product_data->_source->name);
$_product->setTypeId('simple');
$_product->setSku('sku'.$item);
$_product->setreference($product_data->_source->reference);
...
$_product->save();
```

but an error is displayed as following,

[image] please how to add an attribute and access it with set and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> try to use this one

```
$_product->setName($product_data->_source->name);
$_product->setTypeId('simple');
$_product->setSku('sku'.$item);
$_product->setreference($product_data->_source->reference);
...
$_product->save();
```

> I have changed
>
> $_product->setreference($product_data->_source>reference);
>
> to
>
> $_product->setreference($product_data->_source->reference);